# How to get number of URLs already scraped (request_count) from Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Scrapy show stats like this while running code

```
2016-11-18 06:41:38 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 656,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2661,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 18, 14, 41, 38, 759760),
 'item_scraped_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 18, 14, 41, 37, 807590)}
```

My goal is to access `response_count` or `request_count` in `process_response` or any method in Spider.

I want to close spider once N number of total URLs are scraped by my Spider.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to close the spider depending on number of requests done, I'd suggest using [`CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`]in `settings.py`: (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-pagecount)

**settings.py**

```
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT= 20 # so end after 20 pages have been crawled
```

Still if you want to access Scrapy Stats inside the spider, you can do it like this:

```
self.crawler.stats.get_value('my_stat_name') # change it to `response_count` or `request_count`
```